# How to set the serifs on the X and Y axes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

I need to set the serifs on the X and Y axes like on image.

I try to find this feature in docs but found nothing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with chart.js in particluar but I guess they're called *ticks*

Answer (score 0):

options -> axes -> ticks have font properties, which you can set/change before or afterwards.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'some numbers',
            data: [5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1],
   backgroundColor: ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "purple", "orange"],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: "14"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

document.getElementById("testbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
 myChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.fontStyle = "bold";
 myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.fontFamily = "Verdana";
 myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.fontColor = "red";
 myChart.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="50"></canvas>
  <br>
  <button id="testbtn">change font</button>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help, but is not the solution of my problem. You see how looks graph on my screenshot? This is how i want to my graph look, equal like on screenshot. Without a grid lines, only lines like on screenhot.

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand your exact problem. Please, post your code which we can analyze and teach how to get desired result. Word serif in current context is meaningless (least to me).